# get TestContainer to find local docker containers

Tags: testcontainers

I'd like to use TestContainers to get JUnit integration tests going with local docker containers that are either started already, in which case I need to hook into the running containers, or that may be started by TestContainers.

How can I use TestContainers to tell if a local container is already running?
I've tried starting `myContainer` docker image locally and then to see it from a test by running:

```
GenericContainer<?> myContainer = new GenericContainer<>(DockerImageName.parse("myContainer"))
    .withNetworkMode("myNetwork");
```

but looking at the generic container object it's not connected to the docker container running locally:

[image: object]

Comment: Read https://testcontainers.com/guides/getting-started-with-testcontainers-for-java/